# Logs all functions that are executed with a separate program

Tags: c#, logging, capture

This is my first question here and I hope you can help me.

I have had an idea and want to realize the whole thing.
Unfortunately I don't know how to proceed or what to look for. 
My idea is to write a program which logs all executed functions with parameters of a C# application with a separate program.

Can someone help me to find what I can at least search for which gives me an approach.

Thanks a lot.

Regards

Comment: You're talking about writing a *debugger*.

Comment: Logging all parameters at each method call would be increddibly slow, and what would it even do with reference types? The address would not be very usefull, but logging the entire object could be an incredible amount of data. In addition, the runtime is free to inline and remove method calls so you might not see what you would expect.

Comment: My goal is to log all functions first. 
 
With the arguments my goal is to create a simulation. 
 
With the called methods I want to check if the expected methods were called